# Low E-string sounds out of tune

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, tuning, strings, intonation

I have an issue with the low E string on my Acoustic Seagull S6 Original.
Ever since I changed the strings, the E string seems to be out of tune in a weird way. When the open E is right on the spot (using a digital tuner) all the other notes on the fret board are slightly higher in pitch (like a quarter tone). 
The peculiar thing is that it's only on the low E string.

Worth mentioning I went from .10 to .11 gauge.

I checked the nut and the heads and there is no visible damage or anything like that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also related: [Guitar fret out of tune?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/guitar-fret-out-of-tune)

Comment: Check to be sure the string is seated firmly in the nut slot.

Comment: My first move would be to replace the new bottom string with one the same gauge as the original. It *is* the fat E, isn't it? (there's sometimes confusion between high and low - note or position). Fat or thin solves that!

Comment: a 1/4 tone is a lot.  But this is not uncommon.  You may need to adjust the rest of the guitar, truss rod, bridge, etc to accomodate the new gauge.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my experience that was almost identical. I changed to slightly heavier strings, and I had fret buzz on the Low E only at the 9th and 10th fret. I tried replacing to the lighter strings but still same problem. I ended up adjusting my truss rod under the guidance of my guitar teacher. Somehow I had managed to change the action slightly. Perhaps that is something to consider if nothing else has helped.

good luck ~catz